# How to select last entry per ID in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have a big log table with 2 million rows give or take.

I am looking to look for the last entry for each id.

The 3 columns of importance are

- Userid
- Actiontype
- Actiontime
- Text2

Some userids show up thousands of times some just show up once. I need the most recent of each userid. I tried to use 'Group By' but it wont work because text2 is different for each entry which is really the data I need. So it needs to be ordered by actiontime, actiontype needs to be 103. I am really at a loss how to do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ....3 columns?....... :-|

Comment: 2 million rows is not considered "big" these days.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86415/retrieving-n-rows-per-group

Comment: well the 2 million rows are only with that certain actiontype otherwise it has 50 million.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select B.*
 From  (
        Select UserID,ActionTime=max(ActionTime) 
         From  SomeTable
         Group By UserID
       ) A
 Join SomeTable B on A.UserID=B.UserID and A.ActionTime=B.ActionTime
```

Comment: This did the trick, thanks a ton